# How do I get_the_postID() for a custom post that uses ACF repeater field?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Okay so I have a custom post type called Multimedia Gallery. It's built using a repeater field that can take video, image, link, iframe, etc.

[I'm using this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-pages/) to insert these custom posts into blog posts, basically allowing me to insert my MM gallery into blog posts using a shortcode.

Problem is... the If and While statements seem to need a post ID to actually return the correct info. But I'm not quite sure to make that dynamic.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

/*
  Template Name: Gallerys
 */


//Variables

$initialCardLoad = 5;
$loopLazyLoad = 0;
$gridPostID = get_the_ID();



?>

<section class="grid-content">
    <div class="gridGallery">


<?php
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('card', 355) ):

    // loop through the rows of data
   while ( have_rows('card', 355) ) : the_row();
$loopLazyLoad++; // iterate on loop each time you loop through
       // display a sub field value inside a card

        ?>

        <?php
        //VARIABLES//
        $title =  get_sub_field('card_title');
        $childImage = get_sub_field('card_picture');
        $file = get_sub_field('card_video');
        $video = $file['url'];

        if($loopLazyLoad > $initialCardLoad):

            if( $childImage ): ?>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $title ?>" href="<?php
                echo $childImage['url'];//big one here ?>">
                        <img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $childImage['url']; ?>">
                     </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( $video ): ?>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <video class="gallery-video lazy" loop autoplay muted>
                        <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
        <?php endif; ?>
            </div> <?php //end of grid item div

        else : // Note the combination of the words.
        if( $childImage ): ?>
            <div class="grid-item">
            <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $title ?>" href="<?php
            echo $childImage['url'];//big one here ?>">
                <img class="" src="<?php echo $childImage['url']; ?>">
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( $video ): ?>
            <div class="grid-item">
            <video class="gallery-video" loop autoplay muted>
                <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
            </video>

        <?php endif; ?>
            </div> <!-- end of grid item div -->

           <?php endif; //end of initial card load of loop


endwhile; //end of while statement
```

The 355 is a manual insertion of the proper post ID for the purposes of testing if it would even work. It does! But how do I make it dynamic? When I try to use get_the_ID() it just gets the ID of the post I'm inserting into, rather than the one I'm inserting from.

Comment: get_the_id() will always return current post/page ID, one thing you can do is use custom field to store the value (355) in current post and call it dynamically in the template. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @PiyushRawat I was thinking of trying something like that, but figured it would mean having to manually set the ID value in a custom field for every single gallery. If it works though, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the plugin code I can see that it uses `query_posts()` to set up a new context for your template if you're using `display="blah.php"`.

So you should just need to add the loop around your template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Gallery
 */

while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); // <-- Important bit
    if( have_rows( 'card' ) ):
        while ( have_rows( 'card' ) ) : the_row();
            // Stuff
        endwhile;
    endif;
endwhile; // <-- Important bit
```